# How to treat the output of "Select" as an array?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, power-automate

I am writing a Power automate flow to process data from a Sharepoint repository which contains managed metadata fields (columns) with zero or more terms each to generate a list where each row has only one term label. From:

| id | term |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | (none) |
| 2 | term1, term2 |

to:

| id_original | term |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | (none) |
| 2 | term1 |
| 2 | term2 |

I need only the labels of each managed term so I use "Select" to generate an array with only the labels:

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@items('Apply_to_each')?['Type_x0020_of_x0020_material']",
        "select": "@item()?['Label']"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "operationMetadataId": "xxx"
    }
}
```

The input data is:

```
[
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedTaxonomy",
    "TermGuid": "xxx",
    "WssId": 38,
    "Label": "Reading material, article",
    "Path": null,
    "Value": "Reading material, article|xxx"
  },
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedTaxonomy",
    "TermGuid": "xxx",
    "WssId": 91,
    "Label": "Other",
    "Path": null,
    "Value": "Other|xxx"
  }
]
```

The output I get is (seems to be?) an array:

```
[
  "Reading material, article",
  "Other"
]
```

Since I need later to iterate on the list of items and I cannot have empty lists, if the list is empty I used a "Compose" to return a list with only one empty item, otherwise I return the output as is:

```
if(equals(length(outputs('Select_TyMa')), 0), createarray(' '), outputs('Select_TyMa'))
```

However I get an error:

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#length for usage details.'.
```

I searched online but I don't understand what is wrong with my approach. How can I make the last "Compose" work as I described?

Comment: Try using this expression: `if(equals(outputs('Select_TyMa'), null), createarray(' '), outputs('Select_TyMa'))`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I was wrong about the "The output I get is (seems to be?) an array", in fact it was an array inside an object "body".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what I thought from looking at the output window when testing the flow, once I checked the raw output I noticed that the array was wrapped inside a "body" object.

I solved by changing `outputs('Select_TyMa')` to `outputs('Select_TyMa')?['body']`.